# Bridge between ASP.NET MVC 2 server validation and jQuery validation plugin

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc, validation, jquery-validate

Good day!

I use ASP.NET MVC 2.0 with server validation (DataAnnotations + IDataErrorInfo for ViewModel classes).

I can write my client validation by hand using jQuery validation plugin (I've done this for years :)) and this is the only approach when I can get very smart client validation.

But for most cases it will be cool to pull server rules directly to client validation. I've looked here: http://haacked.com/archive/2009/11/19/aspnetmvc2-custom-validation.aspx
but it seems to much code for such common task

Questions (at last):

- What is better solution?
- Will ASP.NET MVC 3 bring anything in this area?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's no magic here. If you are performing some custom validation on your server you need to translate it to the client validation framework you are using. What if you are querying some distant server to perform business validation. How on earth do you expect the client to know about this? And no, ASP.NET MVC 3 doesn't bring anything new in this area.

What ASP.NET MVC 3 brings is [unobtrusive validation](http://weblogs.asp.net/mikaelsoderstrom/archive/2010/10/06/unobtrusive-validation-in-asp-net-mvc-3.aspx) for simple rules and making jquery validate the default client side validation plugin. Here's another [nice article](http://www.asp.net/mvc/tutorials/creating-a-mvc-3-application-with-razor-and-unobtrusive-javascript) about it.

By the way I would recommend you looking at [FluentValidation](http://fluentvalidation.codeplex.com/). It has a great [integration with ASP.NET MVC](http://www.jeremyskinner.co.uk/2010/02/06/fluentvalidation-1-2-beta-2-and-mvc2-rc2/).

Comment: I mean at least support for standard DataAnnotations's attributes (Required, Regexp, E-mail, etc) jQuery validate seems to have all of these. Is this possible without too much code?

Comment: Yeah, standard attributes are all supported. Just `<% Html.EnableClientValidation(); %>` in your view. What ASP.NET MVC 3 brings to the picture is [unobtrusive validation](http://weblogs.asp.net/mikaelsoderstrom/archive/2010/10/06/unobtrusive-validation-in-asp-net-mvc-3.aspx). It uses HTML5 `data-*` attributes on your input fields to instruct the `jquery.validate` plugin about the rules to apply.